# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) with Table View

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am making an application which has nearly three buttons in its `Table View Cell`. One for sharing and the other two for other purpose. Before adding the sharing button code everything was working fine for me , the other two buttons were working great but now as soon as I wrote the function for sharing button I am getting an error in the `'Else'` part in the `IndexPath` statement. Here the cell leads to another view controller. Please help me understand where I am going wrong.

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showView"
    {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController

        let controller = vc.popoverPresentationController



        //vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(265, 400)


        if controller != nil
        {
            controller?.delegate = self
        }


    }
    else{
        //STotal.removeAll()
        let indexpath: NSIndexPath = self.tableViews.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        //error in the above line
       //let DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CellViewController

        var newName : String
        var newDetails : String
        var newTime : String
        var newTitle : String
        var newImage : UIImage


        newName = names[indexpath.row]
        newTitle = breeds[indexpath.row]
        newTime = timeDisp[indexpath.row]
        newDetails = texty[indexpath.row] as! String
        newImage = images[indexpath.row]!

        SName = newName
        STitle = newTitle
        STime = newTime
        SDetails = newDetails
        SImages = newImage

       // DestViewController.SName = newName
        self.tableViews.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexpath, animated: true)


    }

}
```

Comment: What exact kind of bad instruction exception is it? Just `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` is very broadly.

Comment: Do I share the whole error with you?

Comment: Exception messages often include a reason. to know that reason could be sufficient .

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Then something is `nil` which must not. Either the index path as mentioned in the answer or `texty[indexpath.row]` or `images[indexpath.row]!`. Set a breakpoint and find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem might be that when you click on the shared button, the cell does not go into the "selected" state and so the method you call

```
self.tableViews.indexPathForSelectedRow!
```

leads to a crash, because there is not selected row and you force unwrap it.

One possible solution might be something like this:

```
func didPressShareButton(sender: UITableViewCell) {
       let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender)
       // prepare your DetailViewController now / show segue
}
```

Comment: So what do I do now?

Comment: I want the button present in the cell to do some particular action and when that button is pressed I want the information contained in that cell move to the next view.

Comment: To be honest, the code contains multiple problems in architecture. But the quickest way for you might be to have another function between. i will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if an indexPath is actually selected.

```
var indexPath = NSIndexPath()
if let path = tableViews.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    indexPath = path
} else { 
    //Do something if there is no indexPath selected
    return//end function
}
```